# LegitBS(DEFCON) 2014 CTF

Tags: discussion, ctf

[LegitBS 2014](https://2014.legitbs.net) will begin on May 17th at 00:00 UTC.

It seems like team Sec.SE has dissolved. I'm running my own team for me and my friends, but I'm willing to let anyone in. My team will be in #bcsunite on freenode, join and ping me if you'd like to join. Someone might also want to revive the Sec.SE team, so make sure to check the discussion.

Comment: I don't think it has dissolved...wait for a response to your DMZ notification and this post.

Comment: If I remember and I have the time, I'll participate as team Sec.SE and coordinate in the usual chat room.

Comment: After May 1 my semester is over, so I'll be able to take part in these again. I think that some of the key members were just busy this time around, the team hasn't dissolved

Comment: I don't mind joining, though